# How to update property value in model/service when XAML entry element is changed?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, dependency-injection

new to Xamarin forms and MVVM- please forgive me if I am thinking about this wrong.

The files in my app include:

- Model (holds the auto properties for objects from a library that I created)
- View (Each element is initialized to default values and the user has the option to change the values. Each element is bound to it's relative property in the view model.)
- View-model (Contains the binding properties, each of which is set up appropriately for binding using the SetProperty method that calls on the INotifyPropertyChanged method OnPropertyChanged.
- Interface (Contains the signatures for my Service)
- Service (Constructor sets the default values for my model. Concrete implementation of the signatures in the interface. Provides method to access model properties from the view model)

Binding from the view to the view-model is fine and good. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to update the corresponding property in the model from my view model. If I understand correctly, the SetProperty method acts in a pub-sub way with the view-- allowing the view to be notified of any changes and update accordingly. But, do I also use this method to update the properties in my service? I tried to create a separate method, called at the same time of the SetProperty method to update the model property value but that caused the SetProperty method to not get called. I thought about implementing a command but the picker does not bind to a command. Any suggestions welcome! Simplified code below:

Model:

```
 public class Model
  {
    public Device ModelDevice { get; set; }
  }
```

View:

```
<RefreshView x:DataType="local:ConfigViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadModelCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ScrollView Padding="10">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Address Type" />
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding AddressTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding AddressType, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <Picker.Items></Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RefreshView>
```

View-Model:

```
private AddressType _myAddressType;

public AddressType MyAddressType;
    {
      get => _myAddressType;
      set => SetProperty(ref _myAddressType, value);      
    }

private ObservableCollection<AddressType> _myAddressTypes;

public ObservableCollection<AddressType> MyAddressTypes;
    {
      get => _myAddressTypes;
      set => SetProperty(ref _myAddressTypes, value);
    }

 public Command LoadModelCommand { get; }

 public ConfigViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Configuration";

      LoadModelCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadModelCommand());
    }

async Task ExecuteLoadModelCommand()
    {
      IsBusy = true;

      try
      {
        //The service is injected into my BaseViewModel, making it accessible here
          var model = await Service.GetModelAsync();

        // ----- Device Properties
        MyAddressTypes = model.ModelDevice.AddressTypes;
        MyAddressType = model.ModelDevice.AddressType;

      }
      catch (TaskCanceledException tcex)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine(tcex);
      }
      finally
      {
        IsBusy = false;
      }
    }
```

Service:

```
public class Service : IService
  {
    private Model _aModel;

    public Service()
    {
      //Default View Values
      _aModel = new Model {

        ModelDevice = new Device("192.168.0.000"),
        
      };

      // ----- Device Properties
      _aModel.ModelDevice.Label = "L18";
      _aModel.ModelDevice.Simulate = false;
      _aModel.ModelDevice.AddressType = MOD_6_DIGIT;

      //----- Device Address type
      foreach (var addressType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MBClient.AddressType)))
        __aModel.ModelDeviceAddressTypes.Add((AddressType)addressType);   
    }


    public async Task<Model> GetModelAsync()
    {
      return await Task.FromResult(_aModel);
    }
```

Comment: usually there is some sort of action - like the user choosing "Save" or "Next" where you would update your model with the VM properties and then save it.  But there is no one way to do this, it depends on how your app is designed and implemented

Comment: @Jason I ended up calling my async task to update the model from a method in my VM and called the method from the property setter.  But I appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

(Presumably, you are asking about how to pass the picker value back to model/service, rather than a general MVVM question)

### Solution A

Call the command from SelectedIndexChanged event.

**ConfigView.xaml**

```
<Picker SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged"
        ... />
```

**ConfigView.xaml.cs**

```
    private async void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = BindingContext as ConfigViewModel;
        var selectedModel = (sender as Picker).SelectedItem;
        await vm.ExecuteUpdateModelCommand(selectedModel);
    }
```

**View Model**

```
    private async Task ExecuteUpdateModelCommand(Model model)
    {
        await Service.UpdateModelAsync(model);
    }
```

**Service**

```
    //Update method A
    public async Task UpdateModelAsync(Model model)
    {
        _aModel = model;
    }
```

### Solution B

Call the method in properety setter.

**View Model**

```
    private AddressType _myAddressType;
    public AddressType MyAddressType
    {
        get => _myAddressType;
        set
        {
            _myAddressType = value;
            await Service.UpdateAddressTypeAsync(_myAddressType);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**Service**

```
    //Update method B
    public async Task UpdateAddressTypeAsync(String type)
    {
        _aModel.ModelDevice.AddressType = type;
    }
```

Comment: I ended up taking a modified route of Solution B and got it working. It's what I had tried yesterday but my fried, end of day brain didn't realize I had to switch the call order. I did not call an async task because I am not sure that is allowed? Or good practice? Nonetheless I called a method in my property setter in the VM that calls my async task in the service. Thank you for your suggestions, definitely got me on the right track.

Comment: @MelanieMarkarian Actually, I'm not too sure either about calling async there. Normally, I would have a button or so to call the service, rather than changing picker selection. And alternatively, could try [eventtocommandbehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior) from XCT, or write one yourself.

Comment: the reason behind the word "property value" in my question is because specifically I am trying to change the value of the property in my service. The picker is just one example, my page has lots of elements (mostly entries, checkboxes, and some pickers) that when changed, need to update the value of the property in my service to ultimately change the corresponding value in the model. Not sure if it was you that was suggested the edit, but if you did, that is why I didn't accept! I appreciate your feedback though :)

Comment: @MelanieMarkarian Yes, I suggested and I see your point now. I just thought better to talk in code or example. So are those properties all from your "Model"(maybe not listed here), or which properties are supposed to be updated in your service? And one thing I simplified in Solution B is that instead of create another instance of model inside setter and update all properties, I just update the `type` as the picker example.

Comment: Also your picker example is a bit different from the general situation which requires an update whenever the selection changes, as for other elements like entries and checkboxes, there is supposed be a "save/submit" button for the page. That's why I was thinking about a different question, like one for general property update in MVVM, and one for how to update picker property when selection changes.